# Dynamically create MessageSource on startup spring-integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

For a spring-integration project, say I have a config file with different sets of FTP configuration values.  Each set will need to be turned into a MessageSource for the application to all poll from the various FTP sources and insert them into a specific, single channel.

How do I iterate through each configuration set to dynamically create the multiple MessageSources on startup and add them to an IntegrationFlow?  This config file can grow/shrink at any time. Updating the project code dropping in a new @Bean object and going through a production deployment each time the config file is updated is definitely not ideal.

I'll need to basically create a set of MessageSources then iterate through the created MessageSources adding them all to an IntegrationFlow during startup.

Note: The adding and removing of the MessageSources doesn't need to be 'on-the-fly', just pick up the new configuration values on the application startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Spring Integration Java DSL `1.2`, there is a manual `IntegrationFlow` [registration functionality](https://spring.io/blog/2016/09/27/java-dsl-for-spring-integration-1-2-release-candidate-1-is-available). So, you have to iterate your configuration, create `IntegrationFlow` definitions and call `integrationFlowContext.registration(myFlow)` for each of them.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get it working creating the flows through iterating through the configuration values and then registering each flow.